# Is there a smart way to find where the directive is declared?

Tags: javascript, angular

Given the following template

```
<span foo="bar"></span>
```

or

```
<span [foo]="bar"></span>
```

what is the intelligent way (that does not involve mass-grep'ping) to find where the `foo` directive came from?

Assuming the application is large and imports a lot of different modules.

Comment: using some IDE maybe ... ?

Comment: @MajidNayyeri that's not that "intelligent", since it is just nominally better than grep. I'm asking about a general mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we are running our application in dev mode.

I would find it as follows:

[image]

Another way (angular4^):
If you know in which factory that directive is located then

[image]

Comment: Woah! Wouldn't work with a non-running app, but it is amazing, thanks